# Possible to return use validate.js to submit a form without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate, validation

I'm using Jörn Zaefferer's validate plugin for jquery

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Is it possible to use this plugin to validate a form, and have the page not reload when the form is submitted?

The plugin, when used ajaxform, allows you to submit the contents of the form via ajax. However, I've already got my own ajax submission functions that I don't want to rewrite.

So far, I've got something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler : function(form){
            myAjaxSubmissionFunction() ;
        }
    });
```

This is fine, but when validation passes and the submit button is clicked, the page reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent the form to be submitted normally, so only your ajax submission will run.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the `submitHandler` is attached to the form submission event, you could try adding `return false;` at the end of the function body.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ajax form plugin for jquery](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Comment: I'd like to pass the contents of the form to another function, which already makes use of jq's $.post method. I don't want to have to rewrite this function in order make use of the validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return false` at the end of function **myAjaxSubmissionFunction**.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. myAjaxSubmissionFunction makes use of a jquery ajax function that has a success callback. So, the function doesn't actually complete until data comes back from the server. This is too late.

Comment: can you please try it. it worked in one of our case. In the success function you may be showing some message or like that and after that it will execute return false